# Partial siding repair, do I need to add housewrap?

Tags: house-wrap

I had the unfortunate pleasure of having around 3' of siding on one side of my house removed and discarded. Previously there was vinyl on the exterior, then wooden clapboard underneath, then sheathing covered in tar paper. I am trying to figure out how to re-side with the saved vinyl. Part of what I'm wondering is if I should take the time to add housewrap on the exterior of the sheathing, before covering with siding.

Comment: The tar paper is an older type of house wrap.  Replace if any is damaged, but just three feet of house will not help much.

Comment: Where is this? Housewrap is often sold in a long roll. If you do decide to use it, try to get just what you need. I have had 90 ft from a 100 ft roll in my garage for decades.

Comment: Do you still have the tar paper on the walls, or did that go away too?